# keep reading input while program runs

Tags: java, pacman

I'm trying to code a simple pacman/snake game for my upcoming test. Since we won't be using GUI (it's not taught yet, I don't understand it, and I don't know if they allow it), the game will run on console/command line. How can I make my pacman or snake keep moving while the program reads my input?
for example, if I press right arrow or 'D', snake or pacman will head right, and it will keep on running right until I press another button (in my program, it means that X coordinate in my array will keep increasing by 1) I don't know if it's even possible, any help is appreciated

```
static void mapInit(){ // this is the map. I use 10x10 array. I made it so any blank space that pacman or snake can move have 0 value
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
                if(i == 0 || i == 9)
                map[i][j] = rand.nextInt(9)+1;
                else if(i != 0 && i != 9){
                 if( j == 9 || j == 0) map[i][j] = rand.nextInt(9)+1;
                }//else if
                } //second for
            } // top for

    } //mapInit
    static void world(){ // this prints out the map and the snake
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
                if(i == y && j == x) {  // X and Y is the coordinate of my snake or pacman
                    System.out.print("C");
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                    else if (map[i][j] == 0) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                        System.out.print(" ");


                    }
                        else {
                        System.out.print(map[i][j]);
                        System.out.print(" "); 
                        }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


    } // world
```

Comment: yes. Its possible, you can create a *dummy* UI. Assume that you have a 10X10 matrix, then you can mark walls by the value '1' and and other cells with value '0'. Next,You start from `0,0`, if you press right arrow, then move the pacman (which is stationed at 0,0 initially and shown by a unique number / symbol) to its right i.e, `0,1`. If down is pressed, you can go down and (`1,0)`. ou get the idea?.

Comment: Can you show something that you've tried, or what the structure of your program is? Otherwise it will be difficult to provide a useful answer without making massive assumptions

Comment: @TheLostMind I'm not sure what you mean,  I need it that after I press right arrow, it will keep moving to 0,1 0,2 0,3 0,4 0,5 and so on until another arrow is pressed. However, if I use scanner, the program will wait for my input before the snake or pacman continue to move.

Comment: @Rei - then you will have to use *Threads*  with appropriate amount of delay (`sleep()`). Have you learnt threads ?

Comment: Or write a Listener, have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: @Yann4 I've added some of the code.

Comment: @TheLostMind I haven't learn threads, my class never use it. can you elaborate?

Comment: @Rei - You can start by having pacman at 0,0. Next, if user presses `d`, then start a [thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) that moves the pacman to the cell on the right until you press another key. When you press another key, then the thread should be interrupted (stopped) and another threads should be started. That starts moving the pacman in another direction. Clarify what exactly is needed with you teacher.

Comment: @Rei -  *yann's* solution will work if you are *holding* the key. My solution is for just one press.

Comment: @TheLostMind That depends on which event handler you override

Comment: @Yann4 - If the key is *typed once*, then the OP will have to use threads to start moving in the desired direction.

Comment: @TheLostMind I'll read up about threads, maybe that will solve my problem :p

Comment: @TheLostMind Threads just seem like overkill to me, when a `direction` enum and a while loop would do the trick.

Comment: @Yann4 - How do you plan to actually simulate the *movement*?. Without proper delay (`sleep()`), the movement will not be visible.

Comment: @TheLostMind Assuming that he doesn't want pacman running as fast as the processor can carry him, yeah, he will possibly need to do something *like* `sleep` to slow it down, but that would stop all input as well, so it might not be the best solution.

Comment: @Yann4 - Thats why I am asking the OP to use a new thread to keep moving in another direction while the main thread waits for input. :)

Comment: @TheLostMind If it were a proper, gui, graphics, bells and whistles game, sure, but the OP is clearly new, and I think that flinging a new programmer at debugging threaded applications is a little mean. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a `listener` is the thing that you might be looking for. You need to make the class that you've decided should handle input `implements KeyListener` and then override one or more of the following methods to get your desired behavior. On top of this, you need to make sure that your program won't exit on the first run through, so a game loop is needed. There is a more complete example on how to write a `KeyListener` in the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

If you want pacman to keep going in a direction, you could set a `currentDirection` variable that moves him each frame in the direction needed, that's set when you press the key.

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e, "KEY TYPED: ");
}

/** Handle the key-pressed event from the text field. */
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e, "KEY PRESSED: ");
}

/** Handle the key-released event from the text field. */
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e, "KEY RELEASED: ");
}
```

Comment: I barely understand the codes, what does it do exactly? how do I assign my button and how does it know what button I press?

Comment: @Rei - every button will have an associated key-code. You will need to look that up [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: @Rei When you `implement KeyListener`, you get access to these methods that respond to an event being fired. Basically, when you press a key, these methods are entered and run, and you can provide behaviour for them.

Comment: @Yann4 that's weird, my class can't implement KeyListener, eclipse says KeyListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I wrote public class test implements KeyListener { ... } btw

Comment: @Yann4 i've been reading up and trying to use your suggestion lol. thanks for helping, if there's no more answers I'll accept your answer :D

Comment: @Rei let me know if there's anything that I missed that's specific to the question and I'll edit it in, if I can, it's been a little while since I Java'd :P

Comment: @Yann4 actually, I'm still looking of why I can't implement KeyListener to my class. like I said above, eclipse says KeyListener can't be resolved to a type for some reason lol.

Comment: @Rei have you imported it with `import java.awt.event.*;`?

Comment: @Yann4 ah, that fixes it, thanks lol :p still got some more reading to get it to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62115/discussion-between-rei-and-yann4).